# Input type number customization in angular 2

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular5

I am trying to implement a time picker using html5 input type number in angular2 as shown below:

```html
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="hour" (change)="checkHours();" name="one" min="1" max="12">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="minutes" (change)="checkMinutes();" name="two" min="0" max="59">
```

On changing the value (manually entering or by using the up/down arrows in input type), a function should be triggered so that i could modify it in typescript so that single digit time in hours/minutes to be displayed as two-digit ones. as:

if i select/enter values as hour 5 and minute 3 then after function call it should display as "05" in hours input and "03" in minutes input box. But it seems there is some issues like: this.hours does not have the changed value in it. I am doubtful whether I could manipulate number type as string? Please help. Thanks in advance. Any alternate solutions also welcome.

```js
public checkHours(){
  if (this.hours <= 9){
    this.hours = "0" + this.hours;
  }
}

public checkMinutes(){
  if (this.minutes <= 9){
    this.minutes = "0" + this.minutes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please ellobrate on what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest on is this one :

```js
function twoDigits(value) {
  return ('0'  + value).slice(-2);
}

console.log(twoDigits('1'));
console.log(twoDigits('01'));
```

In your case :

```
twoDigits(value: number) {
  value = ('0' + value).slice(-2);
}
```

To call it :

```
this.twoDigits(this.hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because you define hours as number but in your function you assign it a string value and it's not correct:

and you can try:

```
public checkHours(){
  let hours=''
  if (this.hours <= 9){
    hours = "0" + this.hours;
  }
  console.log(hours)
}

public checkMinutes(){
  let minutes='';
  if (this.minutes <= 9){
    minutes = "0" + this.minutes;
  }
    console.log(minutes)
}
```

html :

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="hours" (change)="checkHours();" name="one" min="1" max="12">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="minutes" (change)="checkMinutes();" name="two" min="0" max="59">
```

working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-table-wxqgd1)

Comment: in JS variables aren't typed : you can switch from number to string and vice versa. In typescript, you declare your variables to be both, for instance `hours: number & string;`. The issue doesn't come from that.

Comment: you are right but the problem is you can't assign string to input type number, so it will not work correct.